# how do i integrate an input (instead of a button) on stripe / checkout.js?

Tags: javascript, forms, stripe-payments

i am in the middle of legacy code on a simple checkout form which works fine with a checkout that I'm trying to integrate with Stripe; herein is the legacy code which works:

```
<form method="post" name="submit_order" action="40_SubmitOrder.asp" class="text-center">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input#SubmitOrder').click(function() {
  $(this).val('please wait...');
  });
});
</script>

<input class="btn btn-default default-btn" type="submit" name="SubmitOrder" id="SubmitOrder" value="buy stuff">
```

..I tried using a variation on this with Stripe's checkout.js doing it as a button, and it doesn't work:

```
  <form method="post" name="submit_order" action="40_SubmitOrder.asp" class="text-center">

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('input#SubmitOrder').click(function() {
      $(this).val('please wait...');
      });
    });
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default default-btn" type="submit" name="SubmitOrder" id="SubmitOrder">buy stuff</button>
```

..the Stripe pop up appears fine, but the form isn't submitting.  I've tried variations on form.submit() without luck.  And I'm also trying to do this without using jquery (for legacy reasons).

Here is the Stripe JS that I'm currently using below this form:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_mytestkey',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    // nothing here yet
  }
});

document.getElementById('SubmitOrder').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'legacy checkout site',
    description: '2 widgets',
    amount: 2000
  });
   e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to do it without having to undergo much deeper into the Stripe API?  Thanks!

Comment: `$('input#SubmitOrder').click()` is calling the function you've defined in `document.getElementById('SubmitOrder').addEventListener('click')`, and that function is preventing the form's default action (submit) because of `e.preventDefault();`. One option would be to place a second, invisible button on the page that you programmatically click to submit the form.

Comment: could you suggest an example?